# Scope of object referenced as a delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, nsurlconnection

I need to confirm this.

I have code like this

```
@implementation A
    (void) read
    {
        NSURLConnection *conn = 
           [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        ...    
    }
@end

@implementation B
   (void) someFn() 
   {
      A anObject = [A alloc] init]
      [anObject read]
   }

@end
```

Would `anObject` be a valid object until connection finishes since it is passed as a delegate to NSURLConnection??

Answer (score 0):

If you use ARC, then I suppose it will.

`A` will only be releasable when the connection will be ended, since the one which is holding a reference is that very connection.

Then, you hold another reference to `A` with your implementation in `B`.

So, if `anObject` is unused at sometime in `someFn()` AND has inside reference needing it to be kept alive, it'll be valid until it has no inside reference.